# How to find users who approved a pull request using github api?

Tags: github, github-api

For example, given this pull request : https://github.com/harsh-groverfk/jenkins-demo/pull/16

How to find the list of users who have "approved" the changes in these pull requests.

this is an example review for this pull request : https://github.com/harsh-groverfk/jenkins-demo/pull/16#pullrequestreview-16967726

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by using the [List Reviews for a Pull Request API endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#list-reviews-for-a-pull-request). For the example PR you've listed this would be:

`GET /repos/harsh-groverfk/jenkins-demo/pulls/16/reviews`

This will output all reviews done on a PR (example from the docs):

```js
[
  {
    "id": 80,
    "user": {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "body": "Here is the body for the review.",
    "commit_id": "ecdd80bb57125d7ba9641ffaa4d7d2c19d3f3091",
    "state": "APPROVED",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/pull/12#pullrequestreview-80",
    "pull_request_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/12",
    "_links": {
      "html": {
        "href": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/pull/12#pullrequestreview-80"
      },
      "pull_request": {
        "href": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/12"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql):

```
{
  repository(name: "jenkins-demo", owner: "harsh-groverfk") {
    pullRequest(number: 16) {
      reviews(first: 100, states: APPROVED) {
        nodes {
          author {
            avatarUrl
            login
            resourcePath
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "pullRequest": {
        "reviews": {
          "nodes": [
            {
              "author": {
                "avatarUrl": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/24560176?v=4",
                "login": "alekh2",
                "resourcePath": "/alekh2",
                "url": "https://github.com/alekh2"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't have the specific pull request number, you can query the `pullRequests` field.

Comment: If the approver is a part of a GitHub team, does this response also include onBehalfOf(TeamConnection) field as per the GraphQL API docs? https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#pullrequestreview

I am trying to check whether approval is received from a user that is a part of specific team.

Comment: @harry1102 You can request `onBehalfOf` by requesting it within the `nodes` (alongside the `author` in the example above). You can have a look at the [GitHub GraphQL Explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer) to test.