# Get team name of users approving pull requests

Tags: github, github-graphql

I am trying to fetch the team name of the users who have approved a pull request using the GraphQL API. I am looking forward to perform this operation in a single query. I am able to get the list of reviewers who have approved the request but the team name in the response is empty.

I am trying to look into [PullRequestReviewConnection](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#pullrequestreviewconnection) and [onBehalfOf](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#teamconnection) field for fetching the team name of the approver. This is my query.

```
query { 
  repository(name: "test", owner: "example") {
    pullRequest(number: 2) {
      reviews(first: 100, states: APPROVED) {
        nodes {
          author {
            avatarUrl
            login
            resourcePath
            url
          }
          onBehalfOf(first:100) {
            nodes {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "pullRequest": {
        "reviews": {
          "nodes": [
            {
              "author": {
                "avatarUrl": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/8484848484?u=jdjdjdj",
                "login": "abc-xyz",
                "resourcePath": "/abc-xyz",
                "url": "https://github.com/abc-xyz"
              },
              "onBehalfOf": {
                "nodes": []
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Wondering whether it would be easier to do this via REST API.

Comment: related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697489/how-to-find-users-who-approved-a-pull-request-using-github-api/66767595?noredirect=1#comment135711517_66767595

Comment: Are you sure they're doing it _on behalf of_ the team?

Comment: Not sure about this. Is there an explicit way to approve pull request on behalf of a team? I thought the `TeamConnection` mapping should be implicitly established in `PullRequestReviewConnection`.

Comment: "On behalf of" means the _team's_ review was requested, and one member of that team performed that review. It's unclear from what you've posted whether that's happening or what team(s) you're looking for in the response.